# Two almost identical php mail scripts. One goes to junk, and the other doesn't

Tags: php, email, spam

I have two almost identical mail scripts which sends a user a confirmation email after he has completed an order. The first one pasted below goes straight to outlook's junk e-mail folder while the second one goes straight to inbox as it is supposed to. I've been tearing my hair out because of this and I can't see anything that should send the first one to the junk folder.

1: The script that goes straight to junk

```
$to  = $epost . ', ';
$to .= 'mail@mail.mail';
$subject = 'Ny bestilling fra url.com';
$headers = "From: mail@mail.mail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: mail@mail.mail\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$message = '<h2>Ordrebekreftelse url.com</h2>
<p>Ordre ID: '.$ordre_id.'</p>
<p>Takk for din bestilling. Oblatene vil normalt leveres innen 1-3 dager.</p>
<p>Nedenfor vil du se hva din bestilling inneholder:</p>
<p>Oblater: '.$antall_oblat.' stk.</p>
<p>F&oslash;lgende rekvisita er valgt:</p>
<p>Futteral: '.$antall_futteral.' stk.<br />
Plastlommer: '.$antall_reflekslomme.' stk.<br />
Lanyards: '.$antall_lanyard.' stk.</p><br />
<p>Dersom du har sp&oslash;rsm&aring;l eller har bestilt feil, vennligst send oss en <a href="mailto:mail@mail.mail">e-post</a> med ordre IDen som emnefelt.';
```

2: The script that goes straight to inbox as supposed.

```
$to  = $epost . ', ';
$to .= 'mail@mail.mail';
$subject = 'Ny bestilling fra url.com';
$headers = "From: mail@mail.mail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: mail@mail.mail\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$message = '<h2>Ordrebekreftelse url.com</h2>
<p>Ordre ID: '.$ordre_id.'</p>
<p>Takk for din bestilling. Kortene er sendt til produksjon og vil leveres innen 1 - 3 dager etter at godkjente filer er mottatt.</p>
<p>Nedenfor vil du se hva din bestilling inneholder:</p>
<p>Korttype: <strong>'.$korttype.'</strong> (1 = Uten magnetstripe, 2 = Magnetstripe, 3 = Mifare/ber&oslash;ringsfritt med magnetstripe)</p>
<p>Med de bestilte kortene f&oslash;lger det samme antall oblater med gyldighet for gjeldene periode.</p>
<p>F&oslash;lgende rekvisita er valgt:</p>
<p>Futteral: '.$antall_futteral.' stk.<br />
Plastlommer: '.$antall_reflekslomme.' stk.<br />
Lanyards: '.$antall_lanyard.' stk.</p><br />
<p>Dersom du har sp&oslash;rsm&aring;l eller har bestilt feil, vennligst send oss en <a href="mailto:mail@mail.mail">e-post</a> med ordre IDen som emnefelt.';
```

Answer (score 3):

The only major difference I see is that the `Content-type` differs, the first one is `text/plain` the second one `text/html`. Try to change the first one.

If that doesn't solve it you have something in the printed *variables* that gets recognised as spam.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Tried changing both to plain and both to HTML, but the first script goes to spam and the second goes to inbox just like before.

Answer (score 1):

In your first email you have HTML even though your header says that it is text/plain get rid of the HTML in text/plain as it will not be displayed anyways in user's email boxes.

Answer (score 1):

The email is being rejected because the email client/receiving server is set to drop html emails. In most antispam software html type emails get higher probability of being spam